# Puppeteer - access to outer scope variable fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

```
 const pointName = 'xyz';

 await page.$eval('.popup-dialog input[name=name]', el => el.value =  pointName );
```

I don't get why `pointName` cannot be resolved in this example and I get an
     `Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: pointName is not defined`

Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: I make my bet. Not a puppeteer issue

Answer (score 3):

### Problem

Your function which sets the value is run in the page context. The variables from the Node.js environment are not known in that context and have to be passed as argument to your function.

### Solution

For the function [`page.$eval`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args-1) you pass the following arguments:

1. **Selector**
2. **Function**: First argument of the function will be the element. The following arguments will be the argument passed after the function.
3. **Any serializable value**: Any values passed as third (or even another argument) will be passed as second (or third...) argument to the function.

Putting it all together, you can do it like this:

```js
await page.$eval(
    '.popup-dialog input[name=name]',
    (el, pointName) => el.value = pointName, // executed in the page context
    pointName // this is the variable from the Node.js environment
);
```